# Global contrast normalization and ZCA whitening in preprocessing for CNN: How about test dataset?

Tags: image, classification, preprocessor

I'm studying image classification by CNN and I recently read a paper about preprocessing of images. I understand that when I perform GCN or ZCA whitening for batches of training images, it get better result. But how about when we try to predict other images? Should I do GCN and ZCA whitening also for test dataset? 
Thanks.